# Restricting Menu Item visibility for certain nodes

Tags: routes

Is there a way of customising what pages a Menu item will be displayed on? For example, I would only like one particular menu item in the sidebar menu to be displayed for one node, but the rest of the menu item links I would like to be the same throughout the site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about any module that does what you need. But you could clone you menu (with [Menu Clone](http://drupal.org/project/menu_clone)), remove the particular items and set the visibility to the seperate menus.

Comment: Thanks for that @Volker
Updating a menu item in the original menu will not update the clone, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, after cloning the new (cloned) menu is independent.

Comment: Another way would be doing it by css and I'm sure someone here could write a function or custom module for it. It really depends on your use case.